# Setting 404 page in Nginx

Tags: permalinks, errors, 404-error, nginx

I am using this page (http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress) to setup my WordPress on a nginx/php-fpm server.

Everything is okay, except the `404` page

1. When I request www.example.com/foo, it send me the default nginx 404 not found page
2. I have already set the following, but no luck..

Config:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
error_page   404  /index.php?error=404;
```

I have tried to add some code (e.g. die("wordpress");) in a plugin when I request this page, and clearly that **the request is handled by wordpress already**, but it just can't use the 404.php in the default template.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I'm commenting here only to thank you for linking to that Nginx wiki page that was modified by a person who promoted his site and his plugin all over that page. Fixed it. Thanks again, Yoga!

Answer (score 9):

Remove the `'fastcgi_intercept_errors'` argument from you configuration. It's unnecessary since `'error_page'` declares 404 errors, which should be handled by `index.php`, which will trigger `PHP-FPM` to handle it, and WordPress to present your theme's 404 page.

It seems counter-intuitive, but `'fastcgi_intercept_errors'` is actually causing PHP not to handle the error page.